# Spark wholeTextFiles() reads files in reverse order

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Trying to read TSV files from a local filesystem URL using  wholeTextFiles():

Example URL: file:///tmp/some-folder

Files are returned in reverse lexicographical order. Tried running the same code with an s3n URL and files were returned in correct order.

Is anything can be done to make it return files in correct order?

If not, what would be a better approach to achieve the same functionality?

1. To call sortByKey() after wholeTextFiles().
2. Write custom functions to read list of files in directory, sort that list and proceed from there to load the files and process them further.

Spark version and distro: spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.4

Comment: Is there any particular reason it matters? Order of values in Spark is not something you can depend on in general.

Comment: Do you have references for such statement?

Comment: It is simple. Any shuffle operation results in nondeterministic order of values unless enforced otherwise (by partitioner and post post partitioning operations). Unless your pipeline is expressed only as `mapPartitions` (all `map`s `filter`s etc.) order has to maintained manually (like `sortBy*`). So this is why what you're trying to achieve matters.